# YII - mailing with sendGrid

Tags: php, email, yii, sendgrid

I am trying to send mail with SendGrid in yii php framework.

Here is my action code to send mail:

```
public function actionSendmail()
{
    Yii::setPathOfAlias('Libs', Yii::app()->basePath.'/lib');
    Yii::setPathOfAlias('SendGrid', Yii::app()->basePath.'/lib/sendgrid-php/SendGrid');
    Yii::import('SendGrid.*');
    Yii::import('Libs.sendgrid-php.SendGrid', true);
    $sendgrid = new SendGrid('uname', 'pwd');
    $mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
    $mail->addTo('to-email')->
        setFrom('from-email')->
        setSubject('Subject goes here')->
        setText('Hello World!')->
        setHtml('<strong>Hello World!</strong>');
    $sendgrid->smtp->send($mail);
    $this->render('mail');
}
```

which shows error:

> Use of undefined constant ROOT_DIR - assumed 'ROOT_DIR'
>
> /var/www/apsiap/protected/lib/sendgrid-php/SendGrid/Smtp.php(18)

```
06 {
07   //the available ports
08   const TLS = 587;
09   const TLS_ALTERNATIVE = 25;
10   const SSL = 465;
11 
12   //the list of port instances, to be recycled
13   private $swift_instances = array();
14   protected $port;
15 
16   public function __construct($username, $password)
17   {
18     require_once ROOT_DIR . 'lib/swift/swift_required.php';
19     call_user_func_array("parent::__construct", func_get_args());
20 
21     //set the default port
22     $this->port = Smtp::TLS;
23   }
24 
25   /* setPort
26    * set the SMTP outgoing port number
27    * @param Int $port - the port number to use
28    * @return the SMTP object
29    */
30   public function setPort($port)
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it:

```
    public function actionSendmail()
    {
        define('ROOT_DIR', Yii::app()->basePath . '/lib/sendgrid-php/');
        define('SWIFT_REQUIRED_LOADED', true);
        Yii::import('application.lib.sendgrid-php.SendGrid');
        Yii::import('application.lib.sendgrid-php.lib.swift.classes.Swift', true);
        Yii::registerAutoloader(array('Swift', 'autoload'));
        Yii::import('application.lib.sendgrid-php.lib.swift.swift_init', true);
        Yii::setPathOfAlias('SendGrid', Yii::app()->basePath . '/lib/sendgrid-php/SendGrid/');

        $sendgrid = new SendGrid('uname', 'pwd');
        $mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
        $mail->addTo('to-email')->
            setFrom('from-email')->
                    setSubject('Subject goes here')->
            setText('Hello World!')->
            setHtml('<strong>Hello World!</strong>');
        $sendgrid->smtp->send($mail);
        $this->render('mail');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a chance to take a look at the following links?  The main issue seems to be the way you import the SendGrid library.

- [sendGrid mail function not working in yii-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862546/sendgrid-mail-function-not-working-in-yii-framework)
- http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/32356-sendgrid-and-yii/

Comment: I did that based on SendGrid readme file: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/109730512/README.md

Answer (score -2):

You should not use SendGrid in that way, you have to configure a class or download an aldeary existing extension and set as a mailer component, then you could send emails easyly.

Do not reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: When suggesting alternate ways to solve problems, please enrich your answer with links and/or code. Also, do some research to see how viable is your suggestion.